# How can I copy the repository URL for a line of code in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to click a hotkey and copy the URL for the repo version of the particular line of code I am on to my clipboard (so I can share it with people).

Comment: do you mean the commit id?

Comment: I mean a link to that specific line of code, on the remote version of the branch I am working on - e.g. if I am working on the master branch of the webpack repo, and I am on this line in this file, it gives me this link to the line https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/master/package.json#L2

Comment: I know how to do it in Intellij so I assume this is also a feature of VS

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The extension [Gitlens](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=eamodio.gitlens) by Eric Amodio gives the `Copy Remote URL` option in the context menu.

The command is: `gitlens.copyRemoteFileUrlToClipboard`

Comment: I don't see it in the command palette after installing - do I need to configure anything else?

Comment: @Andrew If I search for `url` in command palette I get 3 hits and 1 of them is from GitLens. Maybe restart VSC.

Comment: Restart, yes, and make sure you open your file from the repo. Otherwise gitLens won't give you list of commands. You can also add a key binding as suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74284047/how-to-copy-a-url-of-code-line-in-vscode/74284072#74284072

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for. 
To have this command works, you also have to configure the remote provider, following this instruction https://github.com/gitkraken/vscode-gitlens#remote-provider-integration-settings-

Answer (score 4):

Put the cursor on the line that you want to copy its Permalink and make a right-click. Then, hover the mouse on the 'Copy As' option and choose 'Copy GitHub Permalink' on the opened window. For this option, you have to install the [official GitHub extension](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/sourcecontrol/github) (which is free).
[image]

Comment: no need for te gitlens plugin. nice! thanks!