# How to copy a URL of code line in VSCode?

Tags: github, visual-studio-code, url, copy, gitlens

It happens often when I work in VSCode and I need to send a code line URL from a repo to a colleague.

There is no native support for this in VSCode. There is a capability that's enabled by Atlassian plugin if you are using Bitbucket. However, I've been looking for a more versatile option.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I copy the repository URL for a line of code in Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63044759/how-can-i-copy-the-repository-url-for-a-line-of-code-in-visual-studio-code)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An answer I found using GitLens:

### Option 1

1. Install GitLens plugin in VSCode
2. Open file from a cloned repo then `Cmd+Shift+P` > type `GitLens: Copy`
3. Click on Settings cog and assign key binding (`Cmd+C+P` is free)
4. Select a line from code in a cloned repo and use your shortcut to copy URL

### Option 2

(ref [How can I copy the repository URL for a line of code in Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63044759/how-can-i-copy-the-repository-url-for-a-line-of-code-in-visual-studio-code))

1. Install GitLens plugin in VSCode
2. Open file from a cloned repo then `Cmd+Shift+P` > type `GitLens: Copy`
3. Run gitlens.copyRemoteFileUrlToClipboard command.

Comment: This method copies url which is usable for vscode users only:

`vscode://eamodio.gitlens/link/r/9f5feef59fe62e4d7687edf1f5cfca285ddbc848?url=git%40github.com%3Acompany%2Frepo.git`


My colleague uses another ide. Is it possible to copy a simple browser link like this:

`https://github.com/company/repo/blob/branch/apps/admin/src/features/client/client.selectors.ts#L8`

Could you explain how, please?